# How do I implement the date range for a custom DatePicker in Swift 5

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building an iOS/iPhone application using Swift 5 / Xcode 14.1. I've created and can display a DatePicker. However, any range I provide, using the `in:` parameter is ignored. How do I correctly set the range.

I've constructed a view with a DatePicker as so:

```
        DatePicker(
            "Please enter the start time",
            selection: $startTime,
            in: ...Date()
        )   .labelsHidden()
            .datePickerStyle( WheelDatePickerStyle() )
```

I am expecting to see a date picker that would allow a date up to the current date and time but instead I see this:

[a datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKyjZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
@State var selectedDate = Date()

var dateClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let min = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!
    let max = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!
    return min...max
}

DatePicker(
    selection: $selectedDate,
    in: dateClosedRange,
    displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute, .date],
    label: { Text("Due Date") }
)
```

This example is working perfectly bro

```
           DatePicker(
                    "", selection: $profile.goalDate,
                    in: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: profile.goalDate)! ... Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: profile.goalDate)!,
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .datePickerStyle( WheelDatePickerStyle() )
```

Wheel stop scrolling and again re position itself to date range

Comment: Your solution does work but unfortunately it does not solve the problem. If you just add `.datePickerStyle( WheelDatePickerStyle() )` to the DatePicker you'll see the range is no longer honored.

Comment: I have edit my answer but both examples working perfectly. One thing keep in mind that wait until the wheel stop scrolling it will automatically scroll itself to given date range.

Comment: wheel date picker doesn't fade out the dates that are not in range it just scroll itself to given date range if you are scrolling it to outside of range

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII, I am getting "minimum" & "maximum" dates from my server. If those both are equal, I am getting 'Fatal error: Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound'. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement a date range.
Not the best solution, but it suits me.

```
let datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        let dp = UIDatePicker()
        dp.datePickerMode = .date
        dp.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        dp.addTarget.....
        
        var minDateComponents = DateComponents()
        minDateComponents.year = 1950
        var maxDateComponents = DateComponents()
        maxDateComponents.year = 2100
        let userCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        if let start = userCalendar.date(from: minDateComponents),
           let end = userCalendar.date(from: maxDateComponents) {
            dp.minimumDate = Date(timeInterval: 0, since: start)
            dp.maximumDate = Date(timeInterval: 0, since: end)
        }
        return dp
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@State private var selectedDate = Date.now

var dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startComponet = Date.now
    let endComponet =  DateComponents(year: 100000, month: 1, day: 1)
    return startComponet ... calendar.date(from: endComponet)!
}


    DatePicker("\(selectedDate)", selection: $selectedDate, in: dateRange, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
        .padding()
```